# Compile asciidoc with latexmath equations

Tags: latex, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am trying to compile asciidoc document which contains some equations, the format is usually the following:

```
.First equation
[latexmath]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\[C = \alpha + \beta Y^{\gamma} + \epsilon\]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

As I understand, I need first to use asciidoc processor to compile this to docbook:

```
 $ asciidoctor -o test.xml -b docbook test.asciidoc
```

The asciidoctor complains about latexmath block, but produces some xml anyway:

```
asciidoctor: WARNING: test.asciidoc: line 3: invalid style for pass block: latexmath
```

Then I try to create pdf using dblatex:

```
dblatex -D --pdf -o test1.pdf test.xml
```

However the produced pdf is just empty, I cannot see my equation whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Particularly I'm trying to compile this document: https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc

I believe the problem is more related to asciidoc rather than tex, but can you help me anyway? How to render this file in Ubuntu?

I already asked this on asciidoctor forum, but nobody answers there...
http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Invalid-style-for-pass-block-latexmath-td2373.html

Comment: Have you tried using a [stem] block? http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#stem for more info.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but this does not work either. The document should be perfectly fine its just I don't know how to render it. I cannot find the contacts of an author to ask him, so I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the the `math` attribute either via the commandline: `asciidoctor -a math` or in the header of the document: `:math:` if you want to do this with html output.

I was not able to get it to work with dblatex nor asciidoctor-epub3, but a plain html should work, you could print to pdf from firefox or chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get rid of both \[ and \], then it works.